# how to reuse deleted primary keys in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

i've got an column named 'id' in a mysql table which also is a primary key that auto-increments.

when i delete rows their id's will also be deleted thus creating "holes" in my id sequence, eg.

1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 30 and so on

is there a way of reusing these deleted id:s?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: cause i use the 'id' as a name for the rows (links). so i dont want these names eg to jump from 5 to 23 leaving a big hole between.

Comment: Do not use your identity for this.  Name your rows during display, that way you separate the visual row number from the internal database key.

Comment: @joe: that is for a security reason?

Comment: It's not a security issue. It's just a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: @noname: Both security and referencial integrity concerns - see my answer for details.

Comment: @weng: What does your schema look like? Likewise, how are you displaying the data such that a "row number" is necessary (or even meaningful)? You may be solving the wrong problem.

Comment: One reason you might want to do this is for tables you expect to get very large, but also have high rate of deleted rows, and want to avoid going into 64-bit autoincrement territory. For some tables like this, I wish there was a table-level setting to continuously reuse ID holes. Of course you wouldn't want to do this if you left behind foreign references to the missing IDs, but if you've been managing your database properly, you could rest assured that it's safe. Computers reuse memory addresses constantly, why can't we do something like that in MySQL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using:

```
ALTER TABLE [your table name here] AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

... will reset the auto_increment value to be the next based on the highest existing value existing in the table.  That means it can't be used to correct gaps of more than one.

The only reason to do this would be for cosmetic ones - the database doesn't care if records are sequential, only that they relate to one another consistently.  There's no need to "correct" the values for the database's sake.

If you are displaying the `id` values to the user, which is why you'd like them to always be sequential, then I'd recommend adding a surrogate key.  Use the surrogate key for displaying to the user, so the values can be re-sequenced as needed but referencial integrity is otherwise unaffected.  The surrogate key in this case would be an integer column.

Comment: This can also be useful in a test environment.

Answer (score 2):

Use a bash script to rename them (this is incredibly slow and inefficient if you have a large database) Then after you've finished, as stated previously use ALTER TABLE to reset the next key to be used

```
TARGET=1
for KEYS in `mysql --skip-column-names -u root --password=Password -D lookup -e "select id from tbl"` ; do
  mysql --skip-column-names -u root --password=Password -D lookup -e "update tbl set id='$TARGET' where id = '$KEYS'"
  TARGET=`expr $TARGET + 1`
  echo $TARGET
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. manually specify the ID (this drops the auto from the auto-increment)
2. `TRUNCATE` the table - this will delete all the records in the table

It's always a bad idea to reuse the "holes" created by deleting rows, this has been answered before here at SO but I'm too sleepy right now to go and find that question.

Comment: how could i manually specify the lowest id? could u show me the php code for it?

Comment: @noname: Like I said in my answer you shouldn't do that, the "holes" as you refer exist to ensure data (relation) integrity, if you don't want to have gaps in your table you'll be better setting a `deleted` flag column in your table when you want to delete a record instead of actually issuing a `DELETE` SQL statement.

Comment: i use id as a link name..so i want it not to have big jumps between numbers..i think ill manually specify the id.

Answer (score 1):

You can try 'ALTER TABLE t2 AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;'

Comment: Worked for me on MySQL 4.1, but see my answer about its ability that might not fit the intended usage.