# Deleting and inserting values in MySQL while leaving index field intact

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a table (Product) with two rows each, one has an index (ID) number 1, the second has and index number 2. Lets say the values in the row of  ID1 are deleted by a user (through a content management interface).

I would like the next inserted values to be in a row marked ID number 1 again (replacing the deleted values) and not in a row with ID number 3.

Is there a way to delete (and insert) values into specific fields while leaving the ID field intact?

Comment: Similar Question here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285906/how-to-reuse-deleted-primary-keys-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you can run an update statement on the particular row;

```
update <table> 
set <column>=<value> where ....
```

You can check the correct syntax here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: I think this might be it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an auto_increment column I'd suggest **NOT** to do so. See my answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643938/mysql-delete-autoincrement/13644089#13644089), if you want to know why.

If you really insist, you could use a table containing numbers from 1 to whatever without gaps and join it.

```
create table foo(id int, something varchar(30));
insert into foo values (1, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (5, 'c'), (6, 'd');

create table bar(minId int);
insert into bar values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6);

insert into foo
select (
select MIN(minId) from foo right join bar on foo.id = bar.minId where foo.id IS NULL
), 'whatever'
;

select * from foo;
```

See it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad0dd9/1/0).

Answer (score -1):

You should run this command just after the delete command

ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1

It will reset the auto increment counter and you will have the desired output.