# How to decrement the sequence on an column with auto increment as a constraint, when records are deleted

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

```
create table quiz(E_Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMAR KEY, E_name VARCHAR(255), E_Salary INT)
```

now whenever i insert data intop table, auto increment works as expected.
Now when i delete the record the sequence of number doesnot get decrement.

Suppose I have a records with Id 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. When i delete the 2 and 3 rd records, the sequence continues from the number 6. I want that if a records is deleted it numbering should get decrement  automatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285906/how-to-reuse-deleted-primary-keys-in-mysql

Comment: why you need?? if you need then do manually don't use auto increment.

Comment: How can i do the decrement if records are deleted

Comment: I am uniquely identifying every record of an Emplyee.

Comment: @J2D8T : This is not a duplicate question. I am deleting record based on an Id

Comment: @user3003685 i.e you want to re use those ID's and by looking at the answers from that post it seems as though it might also solve your problem.

Comment: I simply just want that if you delete a record, the other records id should get adjusted properly in a sequence

Comment: @user3003685 try again with `ALTER TABLE [table name] AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` this would alter table then inc start from 1

Comment: LTER TABLE [table name] AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 doesnot solve. While a new record is inserted, it starts from the id from where it has been left. here like a new record is generated with id as 6, but not 1

Comment: @user3003685 You do NOT want this. Gaps are just fine. And referential integrity is essential.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for auto-decrementing. But you can use other simple methods.

DROP the field you are auto_incrementing.
ALTER the table to ADD the field again with the same attributes.

Then the list of auto-incrementing will reset.

NOTE: Take care when you are DROPing the table. It may drop your entire data.

Answer (score 0):

Update all ids that are above the one been deleted by decrementing by 1 (-1) (if there are 3 id's in auto_increment column and you delete id 2, id 3 will be set to be id = 2) and then "alter table set auto_increment = 1 to update auto_increment counter.
code(including deletion of image file from website folder:

```
$allGood = false; 

if(isset($_GET['id']) != ""){
        $item = $_GET['id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?";
        if($getImgPath = $sqlConnection->prepare($query)){
            $getImgPath->bind_param("i",$item);
            $getImgPath->execute();
            $result = $getImgPath->get_result();
            $row    = $result->fetch_array();
            $deletedItemId = $row['id'];        
            if(isset($row['image']) != ""){
                $imgPath = "../../../../".$row['image'];
                if(unlink($imgPath)){
                    $query = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id = ?";
                    if($delete = $sqlConnection->prepare($query)){
                        $delete->bind_param("i",$item);
                        if($delete->execute()){ 

                                $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
                                if($getIds = $sqlConnection->query($query)){
                                    while($row = $getIds->fetch_array()){   
                                    if($row['id']>$deletedItemId){
                                    $newId = $row['id']-1;
                                    $query = "UPDATE products SET id=? WHERE id=?";
                                       if($updateIds = $sqlConnection->prepare($query)){
                                        $updateIds->bind_param("ii",$newId,$row['id']);
                                            if($updateIds->execute()){                                          
                                            $allGood = true;
                                            }                                                   
                                       }
                                    } else {$allGood = true;}
                                }

                        }
                    }           
                } 
            }
        }
    } 
}

if($allGood == true){
    $query = "ALTER TABLE products AUTO_INCREMENT = 1";
    if($sqlConnection->query($query)){
    echo "success!";
    }else{echo "error.";}   
}
```