# Problems with a primary key sequence

Tags: oracle, sequence, oracleforms

When adding new data to a form my primary key sequence increases by 1.
However if i was to delete a data and replace it with new data the sequence would carry on.

So for example my primary keys for data go 1,2,3,4,5,6,10 because of previously deleted rows.

I hope that makes sence.

Comment: Yes, it is expected behaviour. What is the problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285906/how-to-reuse-deleted-primary-keys-in-mysql

Comment: I am using oracle, not mysql, will this matter? as i can not get the command to work. @span

Comment: @span I receive the error ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

Comment: @Oliver Can you update your question? In one of your comments you mention how to display Primary Key values in Oracle Forms which from my view appears to be totally unrelated to your question as it stands.

Answer (score 2):

`SEQUENCE` values in Oracle are guaranteed to be *unique*, but you cannot expect the values to form a contiguous sequence without any gaps.

Even if you would never delete any rows from the table, you're likely to see gaps at some point, because sequence values are cached (pre-reserved) between different transactions.

Comment: fair enough, do you know how to display primary keys on an oracle application form? They are hidden somehoiw.

Comment: Regarding _"`SEQUENCE` values ... are guaranteed to be unique, ..."_ ... unless there isn't any kind of manipulation to the sequence, e.g. like: `ALTER SEQUENCE SEQ INCREMENT by -4;`

Comment: ... and it isn't set to cycle. The point is valid thouhg, they aren't gapless, even with no cache.

Comment: @Trinimon - obviously we can do daft things to break a Sequence.  So we also need primary key constraints.  The point is, the purpose of an Oracle Sequence is to produce a stream of unique numbers, and nothing more than that.

Comment: @APC: As long as there is an option to do unreasonable things, they will happen. That's for sure. So better you are prepared (and know about it) ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is a SEQUENCE of numbers, it doesn't care if you have used the "current value" or not.
As opposed to MySQL, in Oracle the Sequence is not tied to a column, but it is a separate object that you can ask a value from (through `your_sequence.nextval`). To handle the uniqueness, it doesn't take back values and offer them again.

If you always want to have a dense sequence of ID-s even through deletion, you would have to either

- rearrange the ID-s (read: change ID-s of the rows newer than the deleted one), or
- without knowing your task, I would suggest using the [`DENSE_RANK` analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions045.htm) for querying your dataset, and separating the real (in-table) ID-s from the ranking of the rows.