# how to reset primary key in mysql in rails application if all records got deleted

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a table posts in mysql database in rails application,
when i create a new post then primary key starts from 1 and increment to 2,3,4 on creating three more new posts.

Suppose I delete all posts and then I create a new post then primary key should again start from 1, but it starts from 5.

I have no idea why it is so, since I am new to mysql and rails.

Is there a way to handle this or it is the way mysql database works.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285906/how-to-reuse-deleted-primary-keys-in-mysql

Comment: This relates to the `auto_increment` column attribute. best to accept this behavior until you understand why later. There are a jillion reasons why this approach is your best friend with data quality, staying sane, etc. Don't fret over it, for if you do, you will wonder why you tried to make it better. It is not a bug. It has your back.

Answer (score 0):

Its not recommended to manipulate primary keys, but if you really want to do that you can use `after_destroy` callback in the model

```
after_destroy :truncate_table

private

def truncate_table
  Post.connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{Post.table_name};") if Post.count == 0
end
```