# Inserting new values of a column in previously deleted row ID's place not after last inserted row ID

Tags: php, mysql

I want to assign values to a column 
In this manner

> 1,2,3,4,5,...1000

If I insert values for column

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Using auto increment
Now I want to delete `2,3` 
And the next insertion should be `2,3,` not `8`
After `2,3` is completed then my insertion should start with  `8 ...`

Comment: Okay! Best of luck doing that! Do you have a question?

Comment: you would usually not reuse keys

Comment: You can do this by getting ids before every insert and find missing id till max or last id . Question would be nice if you share some effort.

Comment: bad idea but, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285906/how-to-reuse-deleted-primary-keys-in-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to reuse deleted primary keys in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285906/how-to-reuse-deleted-primary-keys-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` behaves like this; it doesn't fill the gaps arising from deleted data, it just appends the new entries to the "bottom" of the current enumeration. This is because, in a vast majority of cases, it's a very bad practice to reuse unique identifiers.

There is pretty much nothing you can do about it... except changing the design of your table so that the identifier field doesn't have the `AUTO_INCREMENT` property and, then, implementing your own logic to fill the gaps upon insertion. Finding the smallest unused identifier and assigning it to the upcoming insertion is pretty easy:

```
SET @GapId = (
    SELECT MIN(T1.ID + 1)
    FROM MyTable T1
    LEFT JOIN MyTable T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID + 1
    WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
);

INSERT INTO MyTable(ID,...) VALUES (@GapId,...);
```

Comment: @user2486 this is generally considered a very bad idea. There is rarely any need to do whatever it is you think you're trying to do... if you are going to adopt this approach, it has to be inside a transaction